# SQL: Nesting coalesce and convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, coalesce

The version is SQL Server 2012 with SQL Server Management Studio

My assignment requires that I create a table with the columns `PeopleID`, `HireDate` and `TermDate`. `TermDate` is to be renamed to `Current` and have Null values coalesced into 'Current Employee'. The problem here being that `TermDate` is a Null column and needs to be converted into a text column in order to be coalesced...

I have tried numerous adjustments, but I cant seem to figure it out. This is my current iteration. Right now I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TermDate'.

Code:

```
select 
   PeopleID
   ,HireDate
   ,coalesce(convert(varchar(10), TermDate, 1) TermDate, 'Current Employee') as [Current]
from 
   WORKERS
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Your query should have worked without the extra `TermDate` in the middle: `coalesce(convert(varchar(10), TermDate, 1), 'Current Employee') as Current`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  PeopleID
        ,HireDate
        ,case 
            when TermDate is NULL then 'Current Employee')
            else convert(varchar(10), TermDate, 1)
         end as [Current]
    from WORKERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `TermDate` twice in the expression?  You only need it once as the argument to `convert()`:

```
select PeopleID, HireDate,
       coalesce(convert(varchar(10),TermDate, 1), 'Current Employee') as [Current]
from WORKERS;
```